# How to ignore setValue in the .on('input') event (ace.js)

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

```
editor.on('input', function(e, target) {
    console.log(true);
});

editor.getSession().setValue('value'); // How not to handle it in the input event?
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Input event is fired after timeout, and will fire only once if you do several changes quickly.
if you use change event you can do

```
var ignore, changed
editor.on('input', function() { // async and batched
    if (changed) console.log(e);
    changed = false
});
editor.on('change', function() { // sync for each change
    if (!ignore) changed = true
});
ignore = true
editor.getSession().setValue('value');
ignore = false
```

Comment: So Ace's `change` event works like DOM's `input` event, firing instantly on each entered character, which differs from conventionally useless DOM's `change` event which fired only on blur...